# Cobol to Delphi

Tags: delphi, cobol

everybody!
I need to develop an application, in Delphi, to show some data from a COBOL file.
Example: A software made at Cobol has a file of customers with some attributes (ID, NAME AND PHONE). I need to show this data file in a DBGrid of my Delphi program. Is it possible? If yes, how can i do my Delphi program comunicate with COBOL file?
Thanks!

Comment: convert from EBCDIC to ASCII http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Data-on-mainframe-is-in-55779.S.56755230

Comment: text file to DBGrid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338167/possible-to-load-data-form-a-text-file-to-a-dbgrid

Comment: I use ConnectWare - http://www.parkway-software.com/cw_en.html

Answer (score 2):

Typically data written by COBOL programs is done from a "struct" defined in a COBOL "copy book".

You need to get your hands on the copybook; it defines the content and the layout of the data.   That data will be written in an encoding specific to the machine on which the COBOL program ran; it may be a mainframe, so string data may be EBCDIC (not ASCII), and there may be other differences.

You'll have to learn enough about COBOL, copybooks, data encoding, and bit patterns to do this.  Welcome to computing.

With an understanding of the data layout and encoding, you can write a Delphi program to read the binary data and interpret it properly.